# How Do I Add A Column in an MS Access Pivot Table That Is Calculated From The Existing Columns in the Pivot Table?

Tags: ms-access, pivot-table

I need help in adding a column in this pivot table that is "Minutes Per Page".

To compute for the Minutes Per Page, it should be Total Minutes (40) divided by Total Pages (20) so in the table below, the value in the Minutes Per Page column should be 2.00 and not 3.75. 3.75 is the result of Minutes divided by Pages of each individual row and not the Total. I have exhausted my resources and still can't find the answer and so again, I turn to Stackoverflow. Thank you!

[image: Table showing 3.75 because]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *strongly* recommend avoiding building any systems reliant on MS Access Pivot Tables as this feature is deprecated and has been removed from all versions after MS Access 2010.

As an alternative, I would suggest exporting your data to Excel (or using an external data connection from within Excel linked to your Access database), and creating the pivot table there.

You can then easily create a Calculated Field as one of the standard options offered for an Excel pivot table.